# Theme inner field collection field(s)

Tags: 7, theming

I'm looking for a way to theme the inner fields of field collection. Does anyone know, how to do that?

Currently the template output is like this:

```
<div id="someid">
  <div class="somemarkup">
    <div id="someid">
      <div class="somemarkup">
        ... the field collection ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but as you can see, there are now two ids with the same name

Comment: You shouldnt have duplicate ids...

Comment: Sorry @Alex ... I meant, the output is like "this", not my template. The template get's reparsed in itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing is a bug. It happens quite often with contributed code, since it usually moves faster than it is tested. But don't worry, being contributed also means there are lots of people using, and probably someone else will bump into the same issue as you are experiencing.

When you face an issue that looks like a bug, you should ask yourself whether you've configured everything properly. Check first, but if there's nothing obviously wrong, give the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/field_collection) a visit. Every module, theme or profile has an issue queue where people report bugs, suggest features and ask for support.

Search the issue queue and you may find a patch to your issue. If there is no report of your bug, file a new issue and provide a step-by-step guide to reproduce the error. That means you will have to try installing and configuring the module again on a fresh Drupal install. When the module mantainer sees the bug report, the steps to reproduce will make it a lot easier to debug and provide you with a fresh patch.

Mantaining modules/themes are usually voluntary work, and if you don't provide the steps to reproduce nor reply to mantainer questions, your issue will probably be postponed. Get involved with the community, it pays off.

Comment: BTW, your issue has already been fixed: http://drupal.org/node/1658208 I just wanted to take the time and educate you on what to do when faced with contributed code bugs.

Comment: Also, to make finding and referencing this question and answer, try changing your question to "A contributed module is misbehaving, what should I do?" Or something like that ;)